# Musitex: ghost notes implementation

Tags: musixtex

I am a drummer and I need to implement ghost notes in musitex.
Ghost notes are usually are written by putting the notes between round brackets i.e. (note). I cannot find any solution. Could you help me ? Many Thanks
Marco

Comment: musixtex has `\lpar` and `\rpar`, see section 18.8 (Brackets, parentheses, oblique lines and slides) of the manual

Comment: Thanks ! Perfect !